# Getting input from keyboard using Scanner with JavaFX Stage

Tags: java, image, variables, javafx, stage

I have a problem with my application. When I open my application to input my xAxis variable, I have to focus on my "terminal".

What I want to happen is when I'm focused on the Stage, I can still type my variable.

(Where I have highlighted is where I have to focus)
Screenshot of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1RAp.png (I don't have enough Reputation to post a screen shot)

Also some help with the "not responding" might help, but that doesn't affect the program that much.

Code is as follows:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package gamefx;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GameFX extends Application { 

public Image img = new Image("Block1.png");
public ImageView image = new ImageView(img);
public int yAxis = -300;
public int xAxis = 0;
public TranslateTransition  tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(5000), image);
public Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
public String ifelse;

public void spriteAnimation(){
tt.setByY(yAxis);
tt.setCycleCount(1);
tt.play();  
}
public void getMove(){

ifelse = sn.nextLine();
switch (ifelse) {
    case "d":
        rightMove();
        System.out.print("Move Right");
        break;
    case "a":
        leftMove();
        System.out.print("Move left");
        break;
}

}

public int leftMove(){
xAxis = -100;
return xAxis;

}
public int rightMove(){
xAxis = 100;
return xAxis;
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");

    StackPane stckp1 = new StackPane();
    Scene scn = new Scene(stckp1, 700, 700);

    primaryStage.show();
    getMove();
    stckp1.getChildren().add(image);
    image.setTranslateX(xAxis);
    spriteAnimation();
    primaryStage.setScene(scn);



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `scanner.nextLine()` will block your whole application until you press return.

Widget libraries like JavaFX provide [event handling mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm) for processing keyboard input:

```
    scn.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                System.out.print("Move Right");
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                System.out.print("Move left");
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have done more research, I never thought of using an EventHandler.